# Delete element of an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Before randomly voting down my question and suggesting I use splice maybe actually read what I'm trying to do. Thank you.

I'm writing a node.js chat bot and for one of the commands I need to delete a specific element of an array.

This is how the command is supposed to work:

The items 'foo','bar','baz' are added to an array called raidLoot. For each of these array elements an array is created where users can add and for each of those array a random user is selected. So if I have raidLoot = [foo] and a second array called foo = [userA,userB,userC], after one of the users is selected then 'foo' should be removed from raidLoot.

This is the relevant code

```
 case 'loot':
     query(connection, 'SELECT * FROM channel WHERE name = "' + userName + '"').done(function (result) {
         if (result[0].length !== 0) {
             if (args[1] === 'clear') {
                 raidLoot = []
                 send_PRIVGRP_MESSAGE(botId, userName + ' cleared the loot list')
             } else {
                 raidLoot.push(args.slice(1).join(' '))
                 send_PRIVGRP_MESSAGE(botId, userName + ' added ' + args.slice(1).join(' ') + ' to slot #' + raidLoot.length + '. Use !add ' + raidLoot.length + ' to join ')
                 lootSlot[raidLoot.length] = []
             }


         } else {
             send_MESSAGE_PRIVATE(userId, 'You have to join the channel first')
         }
     })

     break;
```

And this is where the my problem is:

```
exports.flatroll = flatroll = function (userId, args) {
    if (raidLoot.length === 0) {
        send_MESSAGE_PRIVATE(userId, 'There is no loot')
        return
    }
    connectdb().done(function (connection) {
        checkAccess(userId).done(function (result) {
            userAc = result
            access_req(connection, 'rem').done(function (result) {
                if (result[0].length === 0 || result[0].length > 0 && result[0][0].status === 'enabled') {
                    if (result[0].length === 0 || result[0][0].access_req <= userAc) {
                        getUserName(connection, userId).done(function (result) {
                            userName = result[0][0].name
                            if (!args) {
                                winnerList = '<center> <font color=#FFFF00> :::Flatroll Results::: </font> </center> \n'
                                for (loot in raidLoot) {
                                    winnerList += '<font color=#00FFFF>Slot #' + (+loot + 1) + '</font> \n'
                                    winnerList += 'Item: ' + raidLoot[loot] + '\n'
                                    if (lootSlot[+loot + 1].length === 0) {
                                        winnerList += 'Winner: No one added \n'
                                    } else {
                                        winnerList += 'Winner:</font><font color=#00FF00>' + _.sample(lootSlot[+loot + 1]) + '</font> \n'
                                        lootSlot[+loot + 1] = []
                                        raidLoot.splice(loot, 1) // This is the line I need a better alternative for.
                                    }

                                    winnerList += '<img src=tdb://id:GFX_GUI_FRIENDLIST_SPLITTER>\n'

                                }
                                send_PRIVGRP_MESSAGE(botId, blob('Winner List', winnerList))
                                connection.release()
                            } // else with args 
                        })
                    } else {
                        connection.release()
                        send_MESSAGE_PRIVATE(userId, 'Access Denied')
                    }
                } else {
                    connection.release()
                    send_MESSAGE_PRIVATE(userId, 'Command Disabled')
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

'raidLoot.splice(loot, 1)' this does work how it's supposed to but the result is not what I need, if there are multiple items added and users join only one of them then the displayed list will contain all items except the last one, the length of raidLoot is modified so the loop doesnt get to the last item and so on for multiple items, less get displayed.

I'm new at node, doing this project as a way to learn so don't be to harsh on my newb code :)

Comment: Please, node + HTML4 hurts my eyes.

Comment: The html is used for an in-game window, this bot is for a MMORPG, there is no fancy alternative as it only accepts very basic html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it works if I split the for loop in 2 separate loops, 1 for extracting a winner and the second for removing the array where a winner was found.

```
if (!args) {
    winnerList = '<center> <font color=#FFFF00> :::Flatroll Results::: </font> </center> \n'
    var rl = raidLoot
    for (i = 0; i < rl.length; i++) {
        winnerList += '<font color=#00FFFF>Slot #' + (i + 1) + '</font> \n'
        winnerList += 'Item: ' + raidLoot[i] + '\n'
        if (lootSlot[i + 1].length === 0) {
            winnerList += 'Winner: No one added \n'
        } else {
            shuffleUsers = _.shuffle(lootSlot[i + 1])
            console.log(shuffleUsers)
            winnerList += 'Winner:</font><font color=#00FF00>' + _.sample(shuffleUsers) + '</font> \n'
        }

        winnerList += '<img src=tdb://id:GFX_GUI_FRIENDLIST_SPLITTER>\n'

    }
    send_PRIVGRP_MESSAGE(botId, blob('Winner List', winnerList))

    for (i = 0; i < rl.length; i++) {
        if (lootSlot[i + 1].length > 0) {
            lootSlot[i + 1] = []
            raidLoot = _.without(raidLoot, rl[i])
        }
    }
    connection.release()
  }
```